# Map function Inside an Array In javascript

Tags: javascript

I know the number one rule of coding is to never repeat yourself ,
My code works perfectly but
How do I go about mapping this  realYears[0] so I can dynamically retrieve the array data inside it without having to repeat the steps 7 times

```
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Total People in IS', 'Backlog With Growth Rate', 'Backlog With Current Delivery Pace'],
      realYears[0],
      realYears[1],
      realYears[2],
      realYears[3],
      realYears[4],
      realYears[5],
      realYears[6],
      realYears[7]
    ]);
```

realYears[] contains

```
0: (4) ["2020", NaN, NaN, NaN]
1: (4) ["2021", 210000, 25000, 24000]
2: (4) ["2022", 220000, 28000, 24500]
3: (4) ["2023", 200000, 28500, 25000]
4: (4) ["2024", 190000, 29000, 25500]
5: (4) ["2025", 250000, 31000, 26000]
6: (4) ["2026", 245000, 32000, 26500]
7: (4) ["2027", 245000, 34000, 27500]
```

So Basically I'm mapping each array row

Comment: Does `realYears` contain other values or is it only length 8?

Comment: `[['Year', 'Total People in IS', 'Backlog With Growth Rate', 'Backlog With Current Delivery Pace']].concat(realYears.slice(0, 8))`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: `arrayToDataTable([ ['Year', 'Total', etc], ...realYears.slice(0,8) ])` .I you want everything in `realYears`, remove the `slice` part. Just `...realYears`

Comment: realYears contains  ```0: (4) ["2020", NaN, NaN, NaN]
1: (4) ["2021", 210000, 25000, 24000]
2: (4) ["2022", 220000, 28000, 24500]
3: (4) ["2023", 200000, 28500, 25000]
4: (4) ["2024", 190000, 29000, 25500]
5: (4) ["2025", 250000, 31000, 26000]
6: (4) ["2026", 245000, 32000, 26500]
7: (4) ["2027", 245000, 34000, 27500] ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for ES6 spread operator.

```js
const array1 = ["E1", "E2", "E3"];

let yourArray = ["your Entry", ...array1];

console.log(yourArray);
```

In your case, it would be:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Total People in IS', 'Backlog With Growth Rate', 'Backlog With Current Delivery Pace'],
      ...realYears
    ]);
```